# Create shared NUnit tests for plugins

Tags: c#-4.0, nunit

I have plugins and i need to test, that any plugin fits to some specification. One of these cases is to check whether some interface exists in assembly (need to reflect from assembly).
I'd like to create some console application which will take plugin as an argument and check it.

This application will contain a set of tests, that will be configured by a passed argument. And the test runner which will produce xml report to output.

Is there better solution?

Update.
In my console application i call:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
        var runner = new SimpleTestRunner();
        var testPackage = new TestPackage(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
        string loc = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        testPackage.Assemblies.Add(loc);
        if (runner.Load(testPackage))
        {
            var result = runner.Run(new NullListener(), new AllTestsFilter(), false, LoggingThreshold.Off);

            var buffer = new StringBuilder();
            new XmlResultWriter(new StringWriter(buffer)).SaveTestResult(result);
            Console.Write(buffer.ToString());

            return result.IsSuccess
                ? 0
                : -1;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

In this soultion i have tests, but i need to pass arguments from command line to this tests through runner..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the TestCaseSource attribute: http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.3

Inside the test case source property you can enumerate the assemblies to test: NUnit will take care to generate a parametric test for each value.

Regarding the command line execution, you can use nunit-console.exe. You can get it here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Runners/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

solved this problem by creation simple console application without NUnit.. Just return code -1/0